# How to show error message in component.ts file?

Tags: angular, api, angular6, angular2-services, angular-services

How to get the error message to my `component.ts` file?
How to access the service class error message to show on `HTML` page?

Component.ts Add method

```
addNew(): any {   this.apiService.addIndexReference(Data.AccessToken,this.indexReference,this.indexId,(result)=>{
              //if Not success
              //
              //else
              console.log("result"+ JSON.stringify(result));
                this.indexReference.id=(result as IndexReference).id;
            })   
        }
```

API service method

```
 public addIndexReference(accessToken: any, body: IndexReference,id:number,action: any) {
    return this.post<IndexReference>(environment.apiUrl + '/api/v1/indexes/'+id+ '/references', accessToken
      , body
      , action);
  }
 public post<T>(url: string, accessToken: string, body: T, action: any) {
    let httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Authorization': accessToken })
    };
    this.http.post(url, body, httpOptions).subscribe(respone => {
      (respone) => this.booleanAddValue = false;
      action(respone);
    }, error => {
      console.log(error);
      return throwError(error);
    })
  }
```

Comment: where are you subscribing?

Comment: subscribe method in API Service ts file

Comment: The subscription to service should always be happening from the components. You can still do the mapping and other operations in service after getting the httpResponse but to have the clean code, make the subscription inside component. This also helps in registering the user actions with these service calls. Ex- if you need to do some action on click of a button, you can handle it in components and make service calls from there. hope this clarifies it a bit.

Answer (score 3):

### Issue

The problem is you are retrieving the data form API and subscribing in the Service class itself.

### Fix

What you can do is, let the Service class handle HTTP call and let the component handle it by subscribing it.

### Modified version

> Service class

```
public addIndexReference(accessToken: any, body: IndexReference,id:number,action: any) {
    return this.post<IndexReference>(environment.apiUrl + '/api/v1/indexes/'+id+ '/references', accessToken
      , body
      , action);
  }  
     public post<T>(url: string, accessToken: string, body: T, action: any) {
        let httpOptions = {
          headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Authorization': accessToken })
        };
        return this.http.post(url, body, httpOptions); //It will return Observable 
      }
```

> Component.ts Add method

```
addNew(): any {   this.apiService.addIndexReference(Data.AccessToken,this.indexReference,this.indexId).subscribe(respone => {
   console.log("Successfull saved");    //<-- SUCCESS
}, error => { 
    console.log("Error occured");       //<-- ERROR
})
```